# Is there any specific way to get a list of all threads from pthread_create?

Tags: pthreads

On linux systems, using pthread_create, we can create a thread. But how do we know the count of threads created?
Is there any way to get that from pthread_create? or any other way which will give us a list of threads created for a process? I am looking for a code sample in C or C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On linux systems, using pthread_create, we can create a thread. But how do we know the count of threads created?

If you need that information, you keep track manually.

> Is there any way to get that from pthread_create?

No.

> or any other way which will give us a list of threads created for a process?

Pthreads provides no API for extracting a list of thread IDs for live threads belonging to the current process.  A pthreads program is responsible for tracking its own threads.

There are various ways to get information about a process's threads, such as `ps H` and the system calls on which it relies, but there's not much actionable information to be had there.  You can get a count, at least:

```
char command[50];
int thread_count;

sprintf(command, "ps H --no-headers %d | wc -l", (int) getpid());
FILE *thread_counter = popen(command, "r");

fscanf(thread_counter, "%d", &thread_count);
pclose(thread_counter);
printf("%d\n", thread_count);
```